# How to properly hydrate Redux state in NextJS on page refresh?

Tags: typescript, react-redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

The problem I'm having is hydrating the user data from local storage on app reload/page refresh.

In my project I am using NextJS for frontend, and for support libraries I am using `redux-toolkit` for redux management across the application and `next-redux-wrapper` for state hydration for the wrapped pages.

The user can log in, and in that case I store the `isLoggedIn` boolean in local storage and in the redux state. Depending on the `isLoggedIn` boolean value I change the `Navbar` component styles (the `Navbar` is included directly in `_app.tsx`).

When the user refreshes any page the `isLoggedIn` boolean is not loaded into the state but is present in local storage.

In the past I have been using `redux-persist` but I have opted out of using it because the `PersistGate` was blocking the UI from rendering until the persisted data is fetched from storage which conflicts with the idea of SSR.

Currently I have the `isLoggedIn` loading problem fixed by using the `App.getInitialProps` method in `_app.ts` which then results in hydration from `next-redux-persist` being called for each and every page loaded, but this introduces another problem: all pages are now server side rendered and there is no NextJS' static page optimisation.

Is there any way to not lose static page optimisation from NextJS, not use the `redux-persist` library and still be able to hydrate the client side store when any page is refreshed?

Current code structure (some code is omitted for simplicity):

`file: _app.tsx`

```js
import { wrapper } from 'store';

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
};


MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);

  return { ...appProps };
};

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

`file: store.ts`

```js
import {
  combineReducers,
  configureStore,
  EnhancedStore,
  getDefaultMiddleware
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createWrapper, MakeStore } from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import userReducer from 'lib/slices/userSlice';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer
});

const setupStore = (context): EnhancedStore => {
  const middleware = [...getDefaultMiddleware(), thunkMiddleware];

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    middleware.push(logger);
  }

  return configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware,
    // preloadedState,
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
  });
};

const makeStore: MakeStore = (context) => setupStore(context);
export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore, {
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
});
```

`file: userSlice.ts`

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { HYDRATE } from 'next-redux-wrapper';

const initialState = {
  isLoggedIn: false
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    login: (state) => {
      state.isLoggedIn = true;
      localStorage.setItem('loggedInData', { isLoggedIn: true });
    }
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(HYDRATE, (state, action: any) => {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
          const storedLoggedInData = localStorage.getItem('loggedInData');
          if (storedLoggedInData != null && storedLoggedInData) {
            const parsedJson = JSON.parse(storedLoggedInData);
            state.isLoggedIn = parsedJson.isLoggedIn ?? false;
          } else {
            state.isLoggedIn = false
          }
        }
      });
  }
});

export const isLoggedInSelector = (state: RootState) => state.user.isLoggedIn;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

`file: Navbar.tsx`

```js
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { isLoggedInSelector } from 'lib/slices/userSlice';

export default function Navbar() {
   const isLoggedIn = useSelector(isLoggedInSelector);
   return (
    <div className={`${ isLoggedIn ? 'logged-in-style' : 'logged-out-style'}`}>...</div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue today. The problem is that we need to decouple the client storage from the page rendering and move it into `useEffect` where the component is mounted. The basic idea is, you first render the page fully and then update the page using the clients storage information.

Directly incorporating the clients local storage can/will interfere with the hydration.

Here is a code sample that i use

```
export default const MenuBar = () => {
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.isLoggedIn);
  useEffect(() => {
    // loads from clients local storage
    const auth = loadAuthenticationToken(); 
    if (auth !== null) {
      // updates the store with local storage data
      dispatch(actions.jwtTokenUpdate(auth)); 
    }
  }, [dispatch]);
  
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return <p>you are logged in</p>;
  } else {
    return <p>please log in</p>;
  }
}
```

For reference, a github issue on NextJS: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17443

And a blog post where window access for rendering is required: https://dev.to/adrien/creating-a-custom-react-hook-to-get-the-window-s-dimensions-in-next-js-135k

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned in the doc that if you use getInitialProps in _app.js, you will lose the static optimization. I don't know why you are using redux on the server side, personally I will advise you to only use it on the client side and you won't need to use next-redux-wrapper anymore because it uses getInitialProps under the hood.

The example with [redux-toolkit](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-toolkit)

Comment: I have read the docs about the `App.getInitialProps` but I am not sure how to avoid it in this case. For some pages I am using `getServerSideProps` to fetch data for SSR. I am using redux-thunk for API calls and they route responses directly into redux. I would not like to skip redux as a single source of truth. Is that maybe a bad reasoning?

Comment: How would we go by restoring redux state from local storage when the app reloads?

Comment: If you have a layout as wrapper, you can do it in layout with ```useEffect```

Comment: and i will suggest you to store your token in ```cookies``` not in ```localStorage```

Answer (score 0):

Also a note, next-redux-wrapper uses getInitialProps on the app.js/ts when you wrap it with your store. So when you use this library and wrap your app with it you will automatically lose static optimization.